# How do I synchronize with SKAction -runAction:onChildWithName:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction

My Enemy class has several methods, e.g. `walkAnimation` and `deathAnimation`, that return instances of SKAction. Because these SKActions involve coordinating basic actions on many child nodes of the Enemy node, `runAction:onChildWithName:` seems to be the way to manage this.

However, according to the documentation (and to experimentation), `SKAction -runAction:onChildWithName:` is instantaneous. That means if such an action is present in a sequence, the next action will fire immediately, instead of waiting for that child action to complete. Similarly, if there is a completion handler, that would be invoked immediately. So effectively, `runAction:onChildWithName:` is nothing more than shortcut for a `runBlock:` action, just like `removeFromParent` is.

As a concrete example of the problem I face, say I have a composite death animation. The sprite backing my Enemy flashes red, and then the Enemy itself is removed from the scene. I can't use `colorizeWithColor:colorBlendFactor:duration:` on my Enemy directly, since that action only operates on SKSpriteNode instances. I can't use `removeFromParent` on Enemy's Sprite node, since that wouldn't completely remove this Enemy instance from the scene. So `runAction:onChildWithName:` is needed.

```
-(SKAction *)deathAnimation {
    SKAction *flashRed = [SKAction colorizeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] colorBlendFactor:1.0 duration:0.2];
    return [SKAction sequence:@[
                                [SKAction runAction:flashRed onChildWithName:@"Sprite"],
                                [SKAction removeFromParent],
                                ]];
}
```

When I run this SKAction, my Enemy node immediately disappears without flashing red. The reason is that `runAction:onChildWithName:` does *not* have a duration of `0.2`. Its duration is instant. Similarly if my SKScene were to use `[enemy runAction:[enemy deathAnimation] completion:^{ ... }];`, that completion block would be invoked immediately.

I would hate to switch to a lesser design. My Enemy class returns `SKAction` instances to give the SKScene precise control over the coordination and composition of these actions. An important aspect to this is being notified of the completion of such actions. `runAction:onChildWithName:` is certainly not up to that standard.

One hacky solution would be to include a `[SKAction waitForDuration:0.2]` in the sequence between `runAction:onChildWithName:` and `removeFromParent`. It's not ideal though. Is there a chance that the `waitForDuration` and `flashRed` actions could finish on different iterations of the run loop? That doesn't really matter for this case, but as soon as you involve multiple actions with multiple completion handlers, I worry about the race conditions might cause.

Do I have other options besides `waitForDuration:`?

Comment: Wouldn't be better to run `flashRed` on `Sprite` node directly? It will have a duration then.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the sequence wrong here, it actually gets in the way.

Get the child node named Sprite. Run the flash red action on it with a completion handler, which in turn removes the sprite (or sprite's parent) by using the removeFromParent method rather than the action with the same name.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I'm using sequence wrong? It takes a list of SKActions, and runAction:onChildWithName: is an SKAction. Also, as I mention in the question, I want SKScene to be responsible for putting actions into motion. Not every node subclass.

Comment: Wrong as in "you needn't use it for two instant actions". With or without the sequence both actions will have the same (undesirable) effect. From a design point of view, I wouldn't have the scene manage all actions but instead have it send messages to individual nodes that they should perform a certain task, and let them pick the proper set of actions. In the long run this approach works better because it makes individual nodes responsible for their own actions.